# reverse vs last for finding the last element in a collection

Tags: clojure

In clojure core the function `last` has been implemented by recursively calling next until the last element is reach.

It could also be implemented as `(first (reverse))`.

Is there any reason performance/readability as to why `last` was implemented this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/653b8465845a78ef7543e0a250078eea2d56b659/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L947) of `reverse` builds a list, so your implementation must hold onto every element of the input sequence before it can evaluate `first`. The implementation of `last` does not need to do this.